# ScrollTo returning and error even though at that location the element is clickable

Tags: java, selenium

I am **scraping** data of a site that requires me to scroll down then click the next button to a new page. Below is my code:

```
WebElement next = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.ng-scope[translate='next']"));
        row = (ArrayList<WebElement>) driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".event-row-container.ng-scope"));
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.scrollTo(0,"+next.getLocation().y+")");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(next)).click();
            next.click();
```

I  end up getting the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
> unknown error: Element ... is not clickable at point
> (360, 14). Other element would receive the click: ...   (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)
> (Driver info: chromedriver=2.42.591059
> (a3d9684d10d61aa0c45f6723b327283be1ebaad8),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.6
> x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
> information)

The site i'm trying to scrape is: https://www.sportpesa.co.ke/?sportId=1&section=today

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has a built in scroll to function, if you use

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("li.ng-scope[translate='next']"));
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(element);
actions.perform();
```

provided that the identifier is correct